# How to save json object variable based on specific value

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read json response from url in python. the below code works fine but the problem is i need to grab the key based on the subject say if **subject** is "*Indices Daily level*" then it should print the following **key** *hkr1omlsnteodhkvnt98q20682ghv1fmegb8de01*
[image]

```
import json, pandas as pd
import urllib

URL = "https://pv-ft-marketdata-store.ihsmvals-dev.com/email/search"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
text = response.read()
json_data = json.loads(text)
print(json_data)
```

Comment: `next(d["key"] for d in json_data if d["subject"] == "Indices Daily level")` ?

Comment: Hi Olvin, thanks for the suggestion, may i pls know what is d here ?

Comment: getting stop iteration error

Comment: It's a current item for `json_data` list which I am iterating over using list comprehension

Comment: i just pasted in my code as it is just before print statement

Comment: `StopIteration` means that there is no element in `json_data` with desired `subject`. I guess it's because in my code sample `level` is in lower case

Comment: next(d["key"] for d in json_data if d["subject"] == "Indices Daily Level")
print(json_data['key'])

Comment: `print(next(d["key"] for d in json_data if d["subject"] == "Indices Daily Level"))`

Comment: sorry assuming a situation, if i had two similar subjects with different pkeys and processed time and had to grab the pkey with latest processed time then what we would have done ?

Comment: Sort it before `json_data.sort(key=itemgetter("processed"))`. Don't forget to import [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: You need to sort data in reverse order *(add `reverse=True` argument in `.sort()` call)* to get item with *latest processed time* otherwise python will sort your list in ascending order.

Comment: many thanks Olvin, i have one more doubt the value(key) that i am getting after using that print statement i am trying to store that value in a variable say (key) and then trying to append that variable in the below URL,  URL = "https://pv-ft-marketdata-store.ihsmvals-dev.com/email/" + 'key'  "/data/html"

Comment: the object is what key i am getting from 1st URL should be used in second URL link

Comment: `a = 'key'` creates variable `a` with string value `'key'`; `a = key` creates variable `a` with value stored in another variable name `key`.

Comment: i tried the below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get first value which match some criteria from list we can pass [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) which iterates over this list with condition straight into [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) which will return first value from passed generator. As you've mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73041747/10824407#comment129005207_73041747) comment, in case if there are two or more values which matches condition you need to get one which has *"latest processed time"* which I assume stored in `"processed"` key of each JSON object in list and contains date in ISO format. To achieve that we can sort list *(using [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort))* in descending order by value of `"processed"` key *(passing [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as `key` argument)* before lookup. And finally you've [*mentioned*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73041747/10824407#comment129014141_73041747) that you need to use extracted `"key"` in next URL, so you need just concatenate it between two URL path parts you provided.

**Code:**

```py
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from operator import itemgetter

with urlopen('https://pv-ft-marketdata-store.ihsmvals-dev.com/email/search') as resp:
    json_data = json.load(resp)
    
json_data.sort(key=itemgetter("processed"), reverse=True)
key = next(d["key"] for d in json_data if d["subject"] == "Indices Daily Level")

URL = "https://pv-ft-marketdata-store.ihsmvals-dev.com/email/" + key + "/data/html"
print(URL)
```

Comment: now i will be trying to grab html tables from the second URL and store the entire table in dataframe using bs4 import beautifulsoup and lxml

Comment: @RahulVaidya, hope you will succeed with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(next(d["key"] for d in json_data if d["subject"] == "Indices Daily Level"))
key = str(next(d["key"] for d in json_data if d["subject"] == "Indices Daily Level"))

URL = "https://pv-ft-marketdata-store.ihsmvals-dev.com/email/" + 'key'  "/data/html"
print(URL)
```

Comment: not getting the key variable in second URL

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73041747/10824407#comment129014166_73041747) comment again. And again. Repeat until understanding comes.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to cast return of `next()` to `str` as it's already string, just remove `str()` call. And if you want to print `key`, just call `print(key)` after you assigned value to variable, no need to call `next()` twice.

Comment: still trying to convince my mind

Comment: Hi Olvin, in case i have a dynamic subject line like "MS strategy daily levels for 2022-07-20", is it possible i only given the subject string till "MS strategy daily levels" and it will fetch its corresponding key ?

Comment: Yes, `if d["subject"].startswith("MS strategy daily levels")`

Comment: something like below ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246610/discussion-between-rahul-vaidya-and-olvin-roght).

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from operator import itemgetter
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re

with urlopen('https://pv-ft-marketdata-store.ihsmvals-dev.com/email/search') as resp:
    json_data = json.load(resp)

json_data.sort(key=itemgetter("processed"), reverse=True)
key = next(d["key"] for d in json_data
if d["subject"].startswith ("Morgan Stanley Systematic Strategies Daily Levels")

URL = "https://pv-ft-marketdata-store.ihsmvals-dev.com/email/" + key + "/data/html"
html = requests.get(URL).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
print(df)
```